# Is there a simple solution to have the same height for 2D and 3D plots in a figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When mixing static 2D and 3D plots, the height of the individual plots are unequal (interactive rotation of the 3D view is not enabled):

[image: Unequal plot bounding boxes]
<sup>Unequal height of bounding boxes (center)</sup>

Why is that? Is there a simple solution to have automatically the same bounding box height (like scaled right hand plot)?

Code taken from [matplotlib.org](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as mtri

u = np.linspace(0, 2.0 * np.pi, endpoint=True, num=50)
v = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, endpoint=True, num=10)
u, v = np.meshgrid(u, v)
u, v = u.flatten(), v.flatten()

x = (1 + 0.5 * v * np.cos(u / 2.0)) * np.cos(u)
y = (1 + 0.5 * v * np.cos(u / 2.0)) * np.sin(u)
z = 0.5 * v * np.sin(u / 2.0)

tri = mtri.Triangulation(u, v)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax.plot (x,y)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, triangles=tri.triangles, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
ax.set_zlim(-1, 1);
```

Comment: The subplots are of the same height - the 3D projection is rotatable and designed that [the largest projection](https://imgur.com/a/RLsCeWq) has the same dimension as the 2D subplot. I would measure the ratio between the two subplots in the specific (initial?) projection you want and reconstruct this ratio using `gridspec`. You can disable the mouse rotation with `ax.disable_mouse_rotation()` and set the desired initial view with `ax.view_init(120, 60)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get locations and dimensions of the subplots, then, change some of them to get better plot. Here is the modified code and the plot it generates.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

u = np.linspace(0, 2.0 * np.pi, endpoint=True, num=50)
v = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, endpoint=True, num=10)
u, v = np.meshgrid(u, v)
u, v = u.flatten(), v.flatten()

x = (1 + 0.5 * v * np.cos(u / 2.0)) * np.cos(u)
y = (1 + 0.5 * v * np.cos(u / 2.0)) * np.sin(u)
z = 0.5 * v * np.sin(u / 2.0)

tri = mtri.Triangulation(u, v)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax1.plot (x,y)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')
ax2.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, triangles=tri.triangles, cmap=plt.cm.Spectral)
ax2.set_zlim(-1, 1);

# get location/dimensiion of both axes
p11 = ax1.get_position()
p12 = ax2.get_position()

# shift left subplot up; also change its width and height
p11_new = [p11.x0, (0.05*p11.height)+p11.y0, 0.8*p12.width, 0.85*p12.height]
ax1.set_position(p11_new)

plt.show()
```

[image: samesize]